# Writing a proper regular expression that handles multiple spaces

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm struggling to write a proper regexp to use with PHP7.4 to extract required information from a string.

Here are the sample strings:

```
Numer właściciela: NOWAKOWSKA                                              01-234 Warsaw
Numer właściciela: NOWAK_S6_2
Numer właściciela: KOWALSKA_S6_                                            01-234 Warsaw
Numer właściciela: NOWACKI S6_                                             01-234 Warsaw
```

What I want to extract is accordingly:

```
NOWAKOWSKA
NOWAK_S6_2
KOWALSKA_S6_
NOWACKI S6_
```

So far I was using the `%^Numer właściciela:[[:space:]](?<owner_id>.+)$%imu` which worked fine (with example from row#2). However, turns out that the other cases (#1, #3, #4) appeared during a roll-out phase and our text extraction is not accurate enough.

The problem here is with spaces, the source text **may** contain space inside the pattern and this space **must** be included in the result. However, if there are repeating spaces, they **must not** be included.

Tried playing around with some conditionals and negative lookaheads to exclude multiple spaces, but failed to do so.

Would really appreciate any help here.

Comment: Use `/^Numer właściciela:\s*(?<owner_id>\S+)/imu`

Comment: Your strings seem to have fixed positions for its content. Why regex? Just extract the parts from index to index.

Comment: Did you forget the rest of line 2 or it's as-is?

Comment: @GillesQuénot No, that's the whole line as it is

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's almost perfect, thank you! However it fails with the last expected result (the one that unf. has a space inside the expected result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a general case, when you want to match sequences of chars separated with a single whitespace, you can use

```
/^Numer właściciela:\h*(?<owner_id>\S+(?:\h\S+)*)/imu
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wStZQG/2). `\h` is preferred to `\s` since you are extracting data from *lines* in a longer text, not standalone texts.

If the strings you extract are all short, you may also use

```
/^Numer właściciela:\h*(?<owner_id>.*?)(?:\h{2}|$)/imu
```

Then, it should be even more efficient, but only if they are that short as in the question. The `.*?` is usually as expensive as `.*` in strings of arbitrary length.

*Pattern details*:

- `^` - start of a line (due to `m` flag)
- `Numer właściciela:` - a literal string (replace   with `\h` to match any horizontal whitespace)
- `\h*` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `(?<owner_id>\S+(?:\h\S+)*)` - Group "owner_id": one or more non-whitespace chars followed with zero or more sequences of a single horizontal whitespace followed with one or more non-whitespace chars.
- `(?<owner_id>.*?)(?:\h{2}|$)` - Group "owner_id" that captures any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible, and then either two horizontal whitespaces or end of a line.

Comment: Thank you so much! That does the trick on the examples above, i'll try running it against all our test data sets.

Comment: @mkrowiarz If the strings you extract are all short, you may also use `/^Numer właściciela:\h*(?<owner_id>.*?)(?:\h{2}|$)/imu`, it should be even more efficient. But only if they are that short as in the question. The `.*?` is usually as expensive as `.*` in strings of arbitrary length.

Answer (score 1):

#### This regex:

```
/^Numer właściciela:\s+(?<owner_id>.*?)(?=\s{20,}|$)/imu
```

[online demo](https://regex101.com/r/gYRT9u/1)